# How to show that $\ln(2) > \frac{2}{3}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to show that $\ln(2) > \frac{2}{3}$. However, I'm pretty stuck on how to proceed.

I tried to show that this is the case using a similar technique to

$$
e < 4 \iff \sqrt{e} < 2 \iff \frac{1}{2} < \ln(2)
$$

However, while I can show that $\sqrt{e} < 2$ (because $2^2 = 4 > e$), I don't think it's easy to do this when $\frac{2}{3}$ is the exponent (at least it's not easy for me).

The other approach I can think of is to use a series expansion for $\ln(2)$, but the only one I know is $\ln(1+x)$ for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Can you see that it's equivalent to $e^2 < 8$?

Comment: I don't know what definition of natural logarithm you're using, but if you know it is the area under the curve $y = 1/x$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, then you can pack that area with enough triangles trapped under the curve to prove the claim.

Comment: @preferred_anon I can. Thank you!

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $e^2 < 8$. It suffices to show that $e < 2.8$.

Comment: Martin is right - I've corrected my comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, considering series like

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...\tag{1}$$

can be interesting but this one has a too slow rate of convergence.

Instead use this one (derived from (1)):

$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2x+\frac23x^3+\frac25x^5+...\tag{2}$$

in which it suffices to take $x=\frac13$ to get:

$$\ln(2)=\frac23+\text{a positive quantity}$$

establishing the claim.

**Remark:**

Series (2) has been used to compute certain values of logarithmic tables before the advent of computers.

Comment: Thanks! That's a really clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 10):

$\ln(2) > \frac{2}{3}$ is equivalent to $e^2 < 8$, so we need an upper bound for $e$. A standard trick is to replace the “tail” of the exponential series by a geometric series, which can be computed explicitly:

$$
 e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}= 1 + 1 + \frac 12  \left(
1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \cdots\right) \\
< 1 + 1 + \frac 12 \left(
1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots\right) \\
= 2 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac {1}{1-1/3} = \frac{11}{4} \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 e^2 < \left(\frac{11}{4} \right)^2 = \frac{121}{16} < 8
$$
and taking logarithms we get $2/3 < \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 5):

You can *define* $\ln 2$ by $ \displaystyle \ln 2 = \int_1^2 \frac 1t \, dt$. Any Riemann sum for this integral with right endpoints will be less than $\ln 2$ because $\dfrac 1t$ is decreasing. In particular, if you subdivide $[1,2]$ into $n$ equal subintervals you obtain
$$\ln 2 > \frac 1{n+1} + \cdots + \frac 1{2n}.$$
You may need to experiment a bit with different values of $n$, but before $n$ gets too large you will obtain $\ln 2 > \dfrac 23$.

Comment: I think you mean either $\ln s = \int_1^s \frac 1 t\, dt$ or $\ln 2 = \int_1^2 \frac 1 t\,dt$.

Comment: For $n=10$ one gets $\ln(2) > 155685007/232792560 \approx 0.66877 > 2/3$.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. $2$ and $s$ aren't even that close on the keyboard - not sure how I did that.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer I just gave.